# Add mongoDB support in slim RESTful API framework

Tags: php, mongodb, slim, database

I am looking on how to add support for mongoDB to slim RESTful API framework. I searched around but could not find the steps. You can answer with steps or link to a page which describes on how to do it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You'll see that the suggested duplicate is also closed as off-topic.

Comment: This is essentially a dup of your previous question, which was closed for either being opinion-based, or a library recommendation.

Comment: @halfer I removed a sentence that was asking for suggestions on frameworks. Now, I think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Akash, okay, so now the on-hold reason would be "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results". Thus, I recommend you do some solid research using a search engine, and make an attempt at using Mongo with Slim. If you are still stuck, _then_ ask a question.

Comment: @halfer May be you are right. But actually I am finding on steps to integrate them and found no link for that. Then how do I move on try integrating?

Comment: You're probably over-complicating it. As Matthew says, use Slim as per the documentation to make your application, but use the standard Mongo PHP calls to start with where you need to write to a document store. You'll probably refactor to a Mongo library at some point (either of your own making or an open-source one) but do the quick and raw version first.

Comment: @Akash Slim's documentation makes absolutely no mention of any kind of database integration whatsoever, and my guess is that the developers deliberately didn't build it into the framework so that developers can use whatever database interface they like. As I mentioned, I used PDO quite happily with my project, and I see no good reason why you could not just use the standard MongoDB interface.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC Slim doesn't really include any kind of database support at all - you just use whatever database interface you want, much as you would with PHP if you weren't using a framework. When I last used it, I used PDO to connect to MySQL without any problems.

You should be able to use the [standard MongoDB interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) without any issues.